# Loading image using CSS animation VS loading using GIF image

Tags: html, css, css-animations, loading

I encounter a problem showing loading a CSS **animation** while doing a heavy JavaScript operation, so wondering if CSS animation is taking more resources than showing a simple loading GIF image, I made the following tests.

1 created page with loading CSS

1. Created page with loading CSS animation
2. Created page with loading GIF image
3. Compared their resources using Chrome task manager

Here are the results:

It looks like CSS animation is using more CPU, and more memory
so basically I want to consult about using CSS animations. Isn't that too heavy? Should I avoid using it in loading cases?

[Loading example using CSS animation](https://jsfiddle.net/eyhobnvr/5/)

[Loading example using GIF image](https://jsfiddle.net/eyhobnvr/3/)

[image: CSS loading animation compare to GIF loading image]

**Here is the code for loading with CSS animation**

**CSS**

```
/* Beautiful loading screen */
#loadingWrap{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 250;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.46);
}
.glyphicon.spin {
  font-size: 36px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 1.822s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: spin 1.822s infinite linear;
  -o-animation: spin 1.822s infinite linear;
  animation: spin 1.822s infinite linear;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 58%;
  transform-origin:50% 58%;
  -ms-transform-origin:50% 58%; /* IE 9 */
  line-height: 0px;
}

@-moz-keyframes spin {
  from {    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);  }
  to {    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  from {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
  to {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
@keyframes spin {
  from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  to {transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
#loadingIcon {
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  line-height: 0px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="loadingWrap">
   <div id="loadingIcon">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-cog spin">Q</i>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Here is the code for loading using a simple GIF image**

**CSS**

```
#loadingWrap{
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      top: 0px;
      z-index: 250;
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.46);
 }
 #loadingIcon {
      z-index: 10;
      position: absolute;
      right: 20px;
      bottom: 20px;
      line-height: 0px;
      background: url(../1-0.gif) no-repeat center center;
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
 }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="loadingWrap">
   <div id="loadingIcon">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Very interesting question, although I suppose no final answer is possible - different rendering engines will be more or less optimized, there may be new developments in the future, etc...

Comment: In the test I made I can clearly see that (on chrome installed on ubuntu) using css animation is consuming more memory around 10 times more, and 22 times more CPU, another interesting thing is when I open the 2 fiddles and compare their resources it looks like the memory difference is getting smaller but the CPU usage is stay the same I guess CPU is working harder when using CSS animations

Comment: For now I decided to use simple gif image, unless someone will convince me that I am wrong

Comment: It's definitely not wrong.

Comment: Yes, i have the same question but for internet bandwidth usage. Does loading CSS takes more bandwidth or a GIF image for same animation. I did some research about it and binary loading and blob vs text loading stuff. But still confused. Have you found any answers after nearly 4 years. please let me know. Thanks. @talsibony .

Answer (score 9):

**Gif images:**

- Positives

  - Performance (small file size)
  - Ease of use &  setup
  - Older browser support
- Negatives:

  - Don't scale smoothly (retina displays, larger images)
  - Image quality(256 color limit)
  - Difficult adaptation & change (need specialized software like Photoshop)

**Css animations:**

- Positives:

  - Easily editable through CSS
  - High quality images and rich colors possible
  - Smooth scaling (retina ready images & svgs)
- Negatives:

  - Performance
  - CSS animations not supported by IE 7,8,9
  - More complex to setup

Comment: what about load time and bandwidth usage? Yes, i have the same question but for internet bandwidth usage. Does loading CSS takes more bandwidth or a GIF image for same animation. I did some research about it and binary loading and blob vs text loading stuff. But still confused. Have you found any answers after nearly 4 years. please let me know. Thanks

Comment: I think Css+html+js is better than loading an external file such as gif for loading animation. I could be wrong.