# Loading Animation with CSS Animations vs GIF images

Tags: html, css, performance, animation

I was wondering what the optimal solution to displaying a loading animation would be.
While gifs probably do not scale very well which could probably be bad for mobile responsive sites it needs a lot less memory than CSS Animations.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31097345/loading-image-using-css-animation-vs-loading-using-gif-image) question but unfortunately, it's around 7 years old and the people in there did not seem to be sure either.

However, I do believe that within the past 7 years something in that area probably changed so I would love to hear your opinion and experiences on this topic.

Comment: For best responsiveness I recommend **self contained svg** loading spinners. They work flawlessly in all modern browsers for quite some time. They work inlined, in `<img>` elements and event embedded via data-urls. Here's a nice [loading spinner compilation on github](https://github.com/n3r4zzurr0/svg-spinners)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, sometimes I'm also seeing GIF not looks good as an animation or loader. It's showed like inner stroke or bad quality. When I face same problem, then I use svg animation or otherwise use animation CSS. But I recommended to use CSS animation, if you're front-end developer.